# mail() function is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, sendmail, contact-form

I have used mail() function in my contact form. But email is not sending. It says mail sent successfully. But not received any mail. No error showing. Checked in spam folder also

```
$name   = $_POST['cuf_sender'.$n];
    $email  = $_POST['cuf_email'.$n];
    $subject= $this->o['subpre'].' '.$_POST['cuf_subject'.$n];
    $msg    = $_POST['cuf_msg'.$n];

    $extra = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $k => $f )
        if ( strpos( $k, 'cuf_field_') !== false )
            $extra .= $this->o[substr($k, 4, 7)].": $f\r\n";


    $headers =
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
    "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"".get_settings('blog_charset')."\"\r\n";
    if ( !empty($from) )
        $headers .= "From: ".get_bloginfo('name')." - $name <$from>\r\n";
    else if ( !empty($email) )
        $headers .= "From: ".get_bloginfo('name')." - $name <$email>\r\n";

    $fullmsg =
    "Name: $name\r\n".
    "Email: $email\r\n".
    $extra."\r\n".
    'Subject: '.$_POST['cuf_subject'.$n]."\r\n\r\n".
    wordwrap($msg, 76, "\r\n")."\r\n\r\n".
    'Referer: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\r\n".
    'Browser: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n";

    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $fullmsg, $headers, $email) )
    {
        echo $to;
    exit();
```

Actually this is in a wordpress website. So i have tried wp_mail function also. But same problem

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: No error message. Only success message is getting

Comment: Are you working in live server?

Comment: Yes. I tried another plugin it is working. But in this method not working

Comment: May I know which contact form Plugin giving this issue?

Comment: A plugin called Sidebar Form

Comment: There may be 2 reasons. 1. The Plugin may not be compatible for the Wordpress version you are using. 2. It may conflict with other plugins that you installed.

Comment: Have you find out any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well , php plain mail() function is sometimes not reliable. I was once in a problem like this. This is no advertising , but I recommend to use PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer It's free. It solved my problem and hoped to solve yours.

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You should start by giving those error message a visual output.
You can turn on error reporting in numerous ways:

1. Apache
   (hxxp://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)
2. [PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/)
3. [Wordpress](https://codex.wordress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

I would really advice starting with wordpress errors, since they'll be more straightforward and more user friendly.

Now on the issue itself, first of all I would look in the config file/admin gui to see if your smpt settings are correct. Also are you testing it locally or is it already up on some hosting?

So, let's summarize, we need more information:

> 1) Wordpress version? 2) Hosted where? (Local/server) 3) Access to a
>   smtp server? 4) Have you tested the files outside of the wordpress
>   installation? 5) Is this a plugin or not?

First link replace hxxp to http, since I can only post 2 links at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Please set your SMTP credentials for using mail function